# Simple dice roller in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, random, dice

My goal is to design a dice game in this way:

Roll 1 die, if this die is even, you get one extra die and you can now roll 2 dice. If every die is even, you get one extra dice, and so on...

My problem is that I can't figure out How can I build a generic way to do so.

Lately I though about something like

- n = 1
- roll n*dice ("roll" would give me a random number) and then check which die is even...

Can someone tell me the best way to go please ?
Thank you

***Update*** 
After your comments, I finally tried to use the NSMutableArray to store my dice values, which works well, expect that once a value is stored into my NSMutableArray, it stays the same and can't be changed like I'd like it to be just like a new dice throw. 
I guess this comes from the fact that my random number is stored in a NSNumber, which is immutable ?
Can you guys please check my code...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{   
//  my int values 
int valueOne = arc4random()%6+1;
int valueTwo = arc4random()%6+1;
int valueThree = arc4random()%6+1;
int valueFour = arc4random()%6+1;
int valueFive = arc4random()%6+1;

//  Wrapped into objects to add to my array
NSNumber* diceOne = [NSNumber numberWithInt:valueOne];
NSNumber* diceTwo = [NSNumber numberWithInt:valueTwo];
NSNumber* diceThree = [NSNumber numberWithInt:valueThree];
NSNumber* diceFour = [NSNumber numberWithInt:valueFour];
NSNumber* diceFive = [NSNumber numberWithInt:valueFive];

//  my array called "myDice"
NSMutableArray* myDice = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:6];

//  add the objects
[myDice addObject:diceOne];
[myDice addObject:diceTwo];
[myDice addObject:diceThree];
[myDice addObject:diceFour];
[myDice addObject:diceFive];

//  Sorting my array
int i;
NSNumber *myObject;

for(i=0;i<[myDice count];i++)
{
    myObject = [myDice objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"\n\nyour die %d is %@.",i+1, myObject);
}


return 0;

}
```

Comment: You have to develop a tree kind of logic. Each leaf will contain an odd value, and once all leaves are odd. your game ends !!! is it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help move you along.

When the program starts you have an array of 1 "die" (this can be an int or a die object). You "roll" that die, generate a random number between 1 and 6 (assuming 6-sided die) for each element in the array. You have a bool even = true, and as you iterate through the array, if a value is odd you just break, if it iterates through without hitting an odd, add another die and repeat.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the idea ... I'm going to try, and I guess I hace to use an NSMutableArray ...

Comment: Yes you'll have to us NSMutableArray. TheAmateurProgrammer's solution works a little better if you don't need to keep track of the values of each die, but you mentioned something about checking "which die is even."

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, all you need is just a simple loop.  No need for any advanced algorithm or an array at all.

```
int dice=1; //Number of dice being rolled
BOOL gotOddDice = NO; //Exits the infinite loop when you get an odd dice
while(gotOddDice==YES) //Creates an infinite loop, which will escape when there's an odd dice
{
    for (int i=0;i<dice;i++)
    {
        int rolledNum = rollDice(); //Function of getting a random number from 1 - 6
        if (rolledNum%2==1) //If the rolled dice is odd
            gotOddDice = YES;
    }
    dice++; //Add another dice
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for this answer. It sounds maybe just like I need. I'm trying to understand it perfectly before trying. Maybe can you comment a bit ?